# Regex testing for special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to test for certain special characters, but I think I am overcomplicating things. The characters I need to check for are: `&<>'"`

My current regex looks like such:

`/&<>'"/`

Another I was trying is:

`/\&\<\>\'\"/`

Any tips for a beginner (in regards to regex)? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
/[&<>'"]/
```

In doing so, any of the characters in the square brackets will be matched.

The expression you were originally using, `/&<>'"/`, wasn't working as expected because it matches the characters in that sequential order. In other words, it would match a full string such as `&<>'"` but not `&<`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you want to be able to match all of the characters you listed, at one time.

If so, you should be able to combine a character set with the `g` (global-matching) flag, for your regex.

Here's what it could look like:

```
/[<>&'"]/g
```

Answer (score -1):

Try /(\&|\<|>|\'|\")/
it depends on what regex system you use